# passing GUID as parameter in WebGet UriTemplate

Tags: json, wcf, http, rest, service

Hello I'm adding WebGets and WebInvokes to existing SOAP service. Here is a method which takes GUID type variable as a parameter. I know that WebGet cannot take anything except string as a parameter in its uritemplate. But if I still do it as in "`http://baseaddress/Rest/GetInstitutionFromGuid?guid=106fbb94-34aa-403c-9400-f186e75e4793`" (106fbb94-34aa-403c-9400-f186e75e4793 is sample Guid)in Advanced Rest Client chrome addon it doesn't give error, but is returning null. Therefore my question is can I pass parameter of type GUID to UriTemplate of WebGet, if I can't what kind of http request should i make to get institution from guid?

Here is operation contract of GetInstitutionFromGuid method :

```
  [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Rest/GetInstitutionFromGuid&guid={guid}&format={format}", 
                       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
            [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Institution")] 
            Institution GetInstitutionFromGuid(Guid guid,String format);
```

Here is its implementation:

```
     public Institution GetInstitutionFromGuid(Guid guid,String format)
            {

 if (string.Equals("json", format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
        }
                Institution inst = db.Institutions.Where(i => i.Guid == guid).FirstOrDefault();
                return inst;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct, but normally the first querystring value is prefixed with '?'  not &.

Comment: yes. sorry I was mistaken while writing this post.edited. It is correct in my project, ie. that is not cause of a problem